# No OS detected ubuntu live usb

Tags: 14.04, boot, partitioning, usb, live-usb

I have inserted an ubuntu 14.04.05 live USB in my computer. I have confirmed the boot order is correct and the USB port is definitely working. I have already reinstalled the iso on the USB, using startup disk creator.

This was working before I tried windows 7. Firstly, I had used the live USB to resize the partitions to make space for windows 7. Everything went ok and then I inserted the windows 7 USB boot. Everything went fine until the part where one has to choose which partition to install windows in. I had formatted the partition as FAT32 but it was not supported by windows, however I easily converted it to the supported format from the windows boot instelf. Then, I figured out I need to convert the partition to MBR to make it work. I hadn't anticipated this so I hadn't taken a backup (that was dumb, I know, sorry). So I put the live USB back in but this time it to backup, but my computer didn't recognize it was an OS.

Please help.

Comment: is this a UEFI machine?

Comment: UEFI & BIOS are not compatible. And Windows only boots in UEFI mode from gpt partitioned drives. Windows 7 installer DVD is BIOS only on MBR partitioned drives. If you want UEFI on gpt, you must copy DVD to flash drive and move some Windows boot files into /EFI/Boot as bootx64.efi to make it UEFI bootable. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh304353(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: @MarkYisri yes the motherboard supports UEFI (msi 970 gaming)

Comment: @oldfred I am installing from a USB which might be MBR. To get the windows boot in GPT, should I just simply move its contents into a GPT USB or is there more to it?

Comment: It is not format of USB. The Ubuntu installer from flash drive can be booted in either UEFI or BIOS boot mode. If system is UEFI, you should get two boot options, one clearly UEFI and the other just name of flash drive which is BIOS. Most require you to turn on some setting to  Allow USB boot. Many work better with Secure boot off, but that should not be required. Since 970, you also need IOMMU setting in UEFI and in grub menu. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2111223&page=5 & http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2292025

Comment: @oldfred just in case I messed up the explanation in my previous comment, the USB I was talking about was the windows boot USB not the ubuntu boot USB.

Comment: In case it has not been made clear, I am trying to install windows but for doing that I need to use the ubuntu live USB (i don't need to install ubuntu).

Comment: This is not a Windows forum. You have to have a Windows flash drive, and would not use Ubuntu for that. You directly boot the Windows flash drive. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2304736 &  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn898504%28v=vs.85%29.aspx & 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn898510%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#RecommendedPartitionConfigurations